# Getter and Setter for element of array inside class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, operators

I have the class `Matrix4f` which have an array of floats named `elements`. I need do some operations with these `elements`, and I do:

```
float* Matrix4f::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > MAX_MATRIX_SIZE - 1)
        return NULL;

    return &elements[index];
}
```

then I call the operator by:

```
*Matrix[index] = 2;
```

I Want use this operator without using * to dereference the pointer to get and set values. So what I want looks like this:

```
Matrix[index] = 2;
float someValue = Matrix[index] * cos(angle);
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Return type `float&` and change return statement to `return elements[index];`

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Richard. What actually hinders you to return a reference?

Comment: If you do go the reference route, change your error handling code to throw an exception.  As it is right now, you'll have undefined behavior if your index is out of bounds and you don't check for a `nullptr` return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a reference instead of the pointer, this will remove the need of dereference to access the value. This will look like this:

```
float& Matrix4f::operator[](int index)
{
    return elements[index];
}
```

However, this will render your boundary checks mute and you will have to add another mechanism, like an assertion. For example you could add

```
 assert(index >= 0 && index < MAX_MATRIX_SIZE);
```

to make sure you are not going out of bounds. You could also throw an exception or whatever seems to be a good idea in your case.